# Como ordenar um select 1 ao 255?

Tags: mysql, select

Pessoal tenho um query de uma tabela com números IPs de 1 a 255 de várias ranges.

Quando faço `SELECT IPS FROM ipvalidos WHERE REDE ='{$rede}' ORDER BY IPS`

Ele seleciona do 10.0.0.100 antes do 10.0.0.11, por exemplo.

gostaria que a seleção ficasse 10.0.0.1, 10.0.0.2, 10.0.0.3 etc...

Answer (score 18):

Você pode usar a função `INET_ATON()`.

O INET_ATON é uma função do MySQL que converte um endereço IP no formato de texto (por exemplo, "192.168.0.1") em um número inteiro sem sinal correspondente.

O resultado é útil quando se trabalha com armazenamento e manipulação de endereços IP em um banco de dados, pois os números inteiros sem sinal ocupam menos espaço de armazenamento e podem ser comparados mais rapidamente do que as representações de texto.

Por exemplo, se você tiver uma tabela com uma coluna que armazena endereços IP como *strings*, poderá usar o INET_ATON para convertê-los em números inteiros sem sinal e, em seguida, armazená-los em uma coluna separada para facilitar a classificação e a pesquisa.

A sintaxe do INET_ATON é simples:

```
INET_ATON('endereço IP em formato de texto')
```

Por exemplo, a seguinte consulta retorna o valor inteiro sem sinal correspondente ao endereço IP "192.168.0.1":

```
SELECT INET_ATON('192.168.0.1');
```

O resultado será 3232235521.

Veja aqui abaixo mais dois exemplos na prática:

> - 10.0.0.100 = 10×256³ + 0×256² + 0×256 + 100 = 167772260
> - 10.0.0.11 = 10×256³ + 0×256² + 0×256 + 11 = 167772171

Sendo assim, seu *script* ficaria desta forma:

```
SELECT IPS FROM ipvalidos WHERE REDE ='{$rede}' ORDER BY INET_ATON(IPS)
```

Coloquei no **Github** o arquivo [example_inet_aton.sql](https://github.com/cleidimarviana/SOpt/blob/master/MySQL/example_inet_aton.sql) para futuras referências e ficar registrado. Caso queira ver funcionando, acesse [aqui no paiza.io](https://paiza.io/projects/xUAmsINoHH6-cfXSSU20-g?language=mysql).

Inclusive, também é possível realizar a operação inversa de `inet_aton`, que seria usar o `inet_ntoa`. A partir de um valor binário (estrutura) ela retorna o endereço em formato string (inclusive com pontos).

Para aprofundar e entender mais em relação à função, veja [aqui na documentação](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/miscellaneous-functions.html) do próprio MySQL.

Comment: Obrigado @Viana! Excelente solução!!!

Answer (score 0):

Visto que são IPs do tipo **IPV4** (só números), pode remover o ponto '.', fazer o `CAST` para número e ordenar normalmente por aí:

```
SELECT      IPS 
FROM        ipvalidos 
WHERE       REDE = '{$rede}' 
ORDER BY    CAST(REPLACE(IPS, '.', '') AS UNSIGNED)
```

Comment: A resposta só faria sentido se os 4 grupos fossem zero-padded (192.168.000.001) - mas nesse caso não precisaria nem dos replace.

Comment: (pegue a sequencia 1.33 vs 11.3 - tanto string como numérico, o 11.3 vai ser considerado menor que 1.33 nessa solução)